# How to install Charles Proxy 4 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, charles-proxy

I was able to install Charles Proxy 3 (sudo apt install charles-proxy3) but unable to find the package for 4.

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/installation/apt-repository/

Comment: well, it is a paid upgrade and I don't think it is available through `apt` but [here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/download/) you can download a trial.

Answer (score 14):

Install GPG public key

```
wget -q -O - https://www.charlesproxy.com/packages/apt/PublicKey | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add repo to your sources -

```
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://www.charlesproxy.com/packages/apt/ charles-proxy main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/charles.list'
```

update sources and install charles

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install charles-proxy
```

The package creates a "charles" command in /usr/bin, and adds Charles in your application menus in your window manager.

Verify -

```
athakur@athakur-Inspiron-7560:~$ charles -version
Charles Proxy 4.2.1
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to perform a manual installation, as it is not yet in the Debian repositories. To do so, just download the tarball from https://www.charlesproxy.com/download/, extract it with

```
tar xvzf charles-proxy-4.1.3_amd64.tar.gz
```

and run the /bin/charles binary with:

```
cd charles/bin
sudo ./charles
```

You may then uninstall charles3 from your computer by:

```
sudo apt-get remove charles-proxy
```